# in Linux, when reading an I2C-based RTC, who handles counter carry-over conditions?

Tags: linux-device-driver, i2c, real-time-clock

When reading multiple bytes from an I2C-based RTC, it seems that it is possible that while reading each byte, one of the values may increment.

For instance, if the time is:

2014-12-31 23:59:59

as you're reading this value, the time may roll-over to

2015-01-01 00:00:00

so you may actually read:

2015-01-01 23:59:59

(depending on which values you read first).

So, is it the rtc driver's responsibility to ensure a reliable read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the datasheet for the [DS1337](http://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS1337-DS1337C.pdf), page 9 states:

> When reading or writing the time and date registers, secondary (user)
> buffers are used to prevent errors when the internal registers update.
> When reading the time and date registers, the user buffers are
> synchronized to the internal registers on any start or stop and when
> the register pointer rolls over to zero.

Therefore, if reading (or writing) occurs with a single I2C operation (without wrapping around), the RTC device guarantees that everything is synchronized.

[I haven't examined the datasheets for any other devices, but I assume they all work similarly.]